# VueJS Promise is failing

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have a products component and a product owner component. Each Product will have an owner

**What I am trying to do**

I am receiving a list of products by calling an API endpoint. When the promise is resolved, I have a list of Products. Each Product has an OwnerID. I am trying to call another API Endpoint to fetch the name of the owner and assign it to the current product being iterated.

**My Code so far**

```
<script>
    var config = require('../config');
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                products:  [],
            }
        },
        ready () {
            this.getProducts().then(t => {
                console.log(t);
            });
        },
        methods :  {
            getProducts : function() {
                let url = config.API.GetProduct

                this.$http.get(url).then(response=> {
                    this.products = response.data.resource;
                    var p = this.products.map(this.getOwner);
                    return Promise.all(p);

                }, error=> {
                    console.error("An error happened!")
                });
            },
            getOwner : function(product) {
                let url = config.API.GetProductOwnerName.replace('[$$$]', product.OwnerID);
                var p = new Promise();

                this.$http.get(url).then(response => {
                    product.OwnerID = response.data.resource[0].OwnerName;
                    p.resolve(currentObj);
                });

                return p;

            }
        }
        components: {}
    }
</script>
```

**Error that I am facing**

Now whenever I am trying to do that, I keep getting the following errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Promise resolver undefined is not a function(…)
```

Can somebody please let me know what I am doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to recreate a new promise object. You can just return the object you want to be passed to the next call.

```
getProducts: function() {
    let url = config.API.GetProduct

    return this.$http.get(url).then(response => {
        this.products = response.data.resource;
        return this.products.map(this.getOwner);
    }, error=> {
        console.error("An error happened!")
    });
},
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am still having the same issue.

Comment: I saw your code. that way even my code is working.  what I really want to do , since I, IMO, have a lot of products i want to handle via promises. In your case, since its a very small object , the promise is resolved quickly and hence you see the message.I might be wrong but that is what i think it is.

Comment: @Gagan It has nothing to do with timing. Promises are meant to work asynchronously.